# How to align Ui Components inside linear layout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

Hi All could someone direct me on how i could align the Spinners and Edit text attached in the screen [image]

Thank you for your help

XML file - below is the layout XML file for the UI screen

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="eudhar.com.eudhar.transaction.MakeTransactionFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Make Transaction"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        style="@style/Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/selectCustomer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Select customer"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/selectTransactionType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:hint="Select Transaction Type"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Amount in Rs."
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTransactionDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Transaction Date"
            android:inputType="none"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddTrasaction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Transaction" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adjusting padding of your spinner.

Comment: how do i achieve this?

Comment: eg. 
        `android:paddingLeft="0dp"`
        `android:paddingStart="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Give **margin** to your `Linear` /`Relative` layout, else share your code, so I can easily give you the answer.

Is this okay?

Comment: margin? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code, i have given paddingLeft and paddingRight "5dp" to the parent layout itself. You may adjust as you need.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
tools:context="eudhar.com.eudhar.transaction.MakeTransactionFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Make Transaction"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    style="@style/Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/selectCustomer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Select customer"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/selectTransactionType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Select Transaction Type"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Amount in Rs."
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="number" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTransactionDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Transaction Date"
        android:inputType="none"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddTrasaction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Transaction" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue as the default text in the spinner shifts to the right and the edit text remains a bit in the left .I wan the the edit text value to come exactly below the spinner values .